# How do I get an aggregated value printed for each transaction?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregation

I will explain with an example.

Let's say I have the following 3 columns in my DataFrame:

```
MONTH-DAY-VALUE
Jan - 2- 2
Jan - 15 - 6
Feb - 5 - 2
Feb - 19 - 1
Feb - 23 - 5
```

Let's say I want the max then the df I want to get is:

```
MONTH-DAY-VALUE-NEWCOLUMN
Jan - 2 - 2 - 6
Jan - 15 - 6 - 6
Feb - 5 - 2 - 5
Feb - 19 - 1 - 5
Feb - 23 - 5 - 5
```

And not:

```
Jan - 6
Feb - 5
```

I have tried:

```
cal['NEWCOLUMN']=cal['Value'].loc[cal['Value']==cal.groupby('Month').agg({'VALUE':'max'})]
```

but this only gives the right value if the value is the max in that row.
Would love to hear your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a transform:

```
df['newcol'] = df.groupby('MONTH')['VALUE'].transform('max')
```

Output:

```
  MONTH  DAY  VALUE  newcol
0   Jan    2      2       6
1   Jan   15      6       6
2   Feb    5      2       5
3   Feb   19      1       5
4   Feb   23      5       5
```

Comment: Actually tried it with transform but I couldn't figure it out. You're awesome, thanks!